# When does Microsoft's MediaPlayerElement fully support webm file?

Tags: uwp, media-player

I'm using uwp `MediaPlayerElement`. Now it seems can play webm file. 
But it does not fire `BufferingStarted` and `BufferingEnded` event.

Comment: There is no mention of support for webm in [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/supported-codecs). At present, there should be no fully support. You can go to the feed back hub to ask questions to reflect. It is the feedback hub that comes with the win10 system. You can find it in the start menu bar.

Comment: I created a user voice: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/38549872-mediaplayerelement-fully-support-webm-file

Comment: Great. Both methods are feasible.